# How to check if Android can open a file by known extension

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I would like to check if `android` have a default excel reader if not show a download link for a reader . Is that possible ?

Comment: i want to open a excel file so i need to check if thre is a  default reader installed or not.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621789/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-android and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170180/viewing-excel-files-in-my-android-app

Comment: @rajshree OP asked how to detect if there is a reader installed. He didn't ask how to open an EXCEL file. The linked articles aren't helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`PackageManager.resolveActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to determine if there is something installed that can view the file. Here's an example:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
File file = new File("filename"); // This is the file you want to show
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
// Determine if Android can resolve this implicit Intent
ResolveInfo info = pm.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

if (info != null) {
    // There is something installed that can VIEW this file)
} else {
    // Offer to download a viewer here
}
```