# Android open XLSX file

Tags: android, excel, android-intent

I'm trying to open an `XLSX` file within my Android App.

I'm aware that the `Intent` type I have to fire is `application/excel`, but despite I've installed `Google Sheets`, my code says that no application can open my excel file.

This is the code I use to fire the `Intent`:

```
private void openXLS(){
        File xls = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "prova.xlsx");
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(xls);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/excel");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        try {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Application available to view XLS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

**Note:** `prova.xlsx` exists, and I'm able to reach it and open it.

Comment: Try saving your file as Excel 2003 (`*.xls`), not as xlsx.

Comment: You might want to write your own reader. A tutorial here: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-read-write-excel-file-using.html

Comment: check out.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877532/how-to-create-docx-files-and-xlsx-files-on-android/22083003#22083003

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18709801/3816340 helped

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Using the MIME type `application/vnd.ms-excel`, `*.xls` and `*.xlsx` files can be opened.

Comment: No only xls files are opened

Answer (score 1):

```
private void openXLS(final String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri uri ;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
            } else {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Application not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```