# Viewing excel files in my android app

Tags: android, excel

I'm working on an Android app in which I have to open & close excel files on button click. These excel files will be readonly. After closing the excel file, it should direct me to the app.

Please suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: Use jExcel API. http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Show some code where you startactivity to open the excel file

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Android 7.0 Update:**

Android 7.0 will throw `FileUriExposedException` if you try to open your app document with an external app. You need to implement FileProvider refer [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38203793/398715).

---

here is a manual route.

[Using JExcelApi in an Android App](http://www.kylebeal.com/blog/2011/10/using-jexcelapi-in-an-android-app/)

[How to read excel file using JXL 2.6.12 jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387478/how-to-read-excel-file-using-jxl-2-6-12-jar)

---

but here is a little more easier one.

[open application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923265/android-how-do-i-open-another-app-from-my-app/2927296#2927296)

but i guess you have to find out the `MIME TYPE`.

**EDIT**

got the mime type as well

[Setting mime type for excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document/1964182#1964182)

**UPDATE**

so something like this might work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


try {
    startActivity(intent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(OpenDoc.this, "No Application Available to View Excel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: @Samuel Not working Android 7.0 please update answer

Comment: @Samuel Android app in which I have to open excel files on button click...same above code is working upto marshmellow 6.0.....But in android 7.1 nougat  it's not opening when i click,,,Please help me sir,,,,

Comment: I Was tried this code `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


try {
    startActivity(intent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(OpenDoc.this, "No Application Available to View Excel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}`

Comment: @Samuel Please try to help sir...i checked `moto E4 Plus`

Comment: @Mariyappan, check the exception it may be an `FileUriExposedException` if so refer the update, else you will have better visibility if you post a question with the exception you are facing.