# Viewing Excel files in my Android App through API

Tags: android, excel, android-webview, jxl

I want to view excel files in my own Android App.

Currently, using my App I can see all google docs. But after clicking on any one doc (for e.g Excel file 'myDemo.xls') , I want to open it in my own app (For Viewing purpose).

I have read  about [jxl](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaExcel/article.html) but the problem with this is that it parses the xls file & the file should be stored in the SD Card.

In my case it is stored in the google drive. (not on SD card)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170180/viewing-excel-files-in-my-android-app) is similar question.

Is there any other way to view xls file through any other API.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

I have used the [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to achieve this.

But the problem is , by using webview I am not able to update the google docs.

I want user to update the google docs using my App through webview.

Below is my code that i've tried up till now,

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

WebView wbView1;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wbView1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wbView1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    wbView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wbView1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    wbView1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wbView1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wbView1.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    wbView1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

    }

// Button on clicking on which I am loading google docs url in WebView.
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    wbView1.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15L4VenowOI0WPO52ASSjRgf90LcNxuJg8VF87_DtTp8/edit#gid=1311977634");

    return;
}


public class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       view.loadUrl(url);
       return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {       
        view.loadUrl("javascript:document.forms[0].q.value='[android]'"); 
    }

 }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.webviewdemo.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".4" 
    android:clickable="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.webviewdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.webviewdemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Can the google docs be edited inside WebView or Google Drive API is required for editing the docs?

I am really confused . Pls help.

Comment: https://github.com/dennis-sheil/android-spreadsheet

Comment: @ Dhaval: Thanks for your quick reply :) But this not the solution I am looking for. I only want to open the xls file not parse it. I think  [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) can be the solution. But it opens browser viz. an external application.Hence, My new question is that Can WebView be used to open browser within my Application?

Comment: any solution for this matter ?

Comment: @user987760 Nope