# Viewing excel file in android as it is

Tags: android, excel, api

Heres [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526058/viewing-excel-files-in-my-android-app-through-api) which i checked.Is there any way to view Excel file as it is in our Android app.
Means, when a button is clicked the file, should be opened and look as if the file is opened in MS Excel and not beeing passed through text views and all

Comment: Then try to read it `ACTION_VIEW` with choose option to open file in other application.

Comment: Is there any way to open in my app @NitinPatel

Comment: AFAIK that will be not easy. And if you find it then please attach solution here.