# How to open xls file programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, xls

Hi I have opened PDF file using following code

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                             marketIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.adobe.reader"));
                             startActivity(marketIntent);
```

Now i want to do same with XLS file
How should i do this??
Please suggest...

Comment: That code does not open a PDF file. It opens a Play Store listing for a specific PDF viewer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170180/viewing-excel-files-in-my-android-app

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work and open an XLS in another XLS viewer application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

try {
    startActivity(intent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this, "No Application Available to View Excel", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```