# Spreadsheet specific file on button click

Tags: android, android-studio, google-sheets, spreadsheet, android-button

I want to open the google spreadsheet on my own app on button click , the file is all ready created on google sheet. this is my code to open the sheet application from my app , but I want to open that specific file on button click in my own app.

```
showBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets");
            if (launchIntent != null) {
                startActivity(launchIntent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ClassActivity.this, "There is no package available in android", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170180/viewing-excel-files-in-my-android-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viewing excel files in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170180/viewing-excel-files-in-my-android-app)