# File not found exception Android java

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app and I want to read an xsl file. I have following code

```
    File rootPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   try {
    File randomContactsFile = new File(rootPath.getPath()+"/assets/LoginTest.xlsx");
    System.out.println(randomContactsFile.exists());
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
```

`randomContactsFile.exists()` returns false and I'm getting file not found exception.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check if the file is present on the sd card in assets folder??

Comment: *randomContactsFile.exists() return false and getting file not found exception.* That's obvious isn't it !

Comment: it means that the file is not present in the path specified

Comment: file is present there so why i have post the problem

Comment: Are you sure you have the sd card permission

Answer (score 3):

May This Help you:

You will not be able to access `assets/` at runtime using `File`. 
 You access `assets/` at runtime using `AssetManager`, which you can get via `getResources().getAssets()`.

**Like:**

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
```

And use `assetManager.open(your file name);`

**Edit:**

```
InputStream is = //Open file, and get inputstream
Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
int totalSheets = workBook.getNumberOfSheets();
for (int i = 0; i <= totalSheets - 1; i++) {
  Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(i);
  // Do something with the sheet
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my eclipse not recognizing getAssets() method. do we need to use context?  Actually i want to open a xls file with FileInputStream

Comment: @itin: yes buddy it uses context.. if your class extends Activity then it will not require otherwise you will need it...

Comment: but actually i can not extends the Activity class as i have already extends the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. I want to read xls file using poi which need FileInputStream.

Comment: my code is fis = new FileInputStream(path);  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);  so context.getResources().getAssets().open not work i think... please advice...

Comment: buddy see the edit and refer this link it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387478/how-to-read-excel-file-using-jxl-2-6-12-jar

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

if you get this exception even when you are sure that you have included all the jars then create a libs folder in the project root directory and copy all jars in libs folder. the add these jars in java build path (select all jars and right click add jars.)